# Detectar si la Localización está activado en Android

Tags: java, android, gps

Necesito detectar si el usuario tiene la localización activada, para mostrar advertencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora mismo uso la combinación de esas dos `isGPSProvider` y `isNetworkProvider`

```
public class LocationUtils {

    public static boolean isGPSProvider(Context context) {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    public static boolean isNetowrkProvider(Context context) {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

}
```

¿Me pregunto si hay otra método más eficiente?

Es decir ahora mismo para detectar si la localización (el interruptor en el ajustes rápidos) lo detecto obteniendo del `isGPSProvider` y `isNetworkProvider`, ambos deben devolver `false`.

El usuario puede tener activado la localización solo con posiciones de bajo consumo.

Creo que seria más optimo obtener el estado del interruptor localización si está activo o desactivado. Me pregunto si se puede obtener directamente de Settings del sistema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola amigo WebServeis, te refieres a eficiencia en cuanto evitar peticiones y por lo tanto no consumir bateria?

Comment: Si por ejemplo obtener el valor del interruptor de GPS, creo que seria más eficiente

Comment: Me confunde tu pregunta "Obtener el estado del interruptor Activar y desactivar el GPS." Veo tu codigo y al parecer ya obtienes si el interruptor esta Activo o no, lo que quieres es poder activarlo/desactivarlo dentro de tu app?

Comment: El código lo que hace es comprobar que proveador hay disponible, es decir si es del GPS o del Network, es decir puede que el usuario tenga activado "localización" pero dentro tenga desactivado GPS pero activado obtener de la red. Yo pregunto si hay una forma más rápida, es decir obtener true o false del interrutpor "localización", edito mejor la pregunta para aclarar

Answer (score 3):

En realidad no hay forma de obtener el valor del switch de los "settigs" pero el método que podrías utilizar es:

```
private boolean checkIfLocationOpened() {
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    System.out.println("Provider contains=> " + provider);
    if (provider.contains("gps") || provider.contains("network")){
        return true;
     }
  return false;
}
```

Si los servicios de localización se encuentra activados, retornará `true`, si están desactivados `false`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

incluso también:

Si se tiene activado el **modo de alta eficiencia** detectará ambos proveedores (`gps` y `network`) como indica la descripción, y retornará `true`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se tiene activado el **ahorro de batería** únicamente detectara el proveedor de red (`network`) y retornará `true`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se tiene activado el **solo dispositivo** únicamente detectara el proveedor de GPS (`gps`) y retornará `true`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]